# Communication between two different versions of python

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7, python-3.x, win32com

I am using python 3.2 to build my windows application in which a DLL has to be created in addition to my application exe.

I googled and got py2exe can create a DLL from python script but supports till python 2.7 or 3.1 and not supported for python 3.2.

Hence I used python 2.7 py2exe to create DLL with pywin32. And while testing my app scripts with python 3.2 which also uses pywin32(py3.2) and sends some arguments to created DLL(py2.7) which uses py2win32(py2.7).

> Got an execution error as follows  
>  "pythoncom error: PythonCOM Server - The 'win32com.server.policy' module could no
>   t be loaded.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com__init__.py", line 5, in   
>    import win32api, sys, os  
>  ImportError: Module use of python32.dll conflicts with this version of Python.  
>  pythoncom error: CPyFactory::CreateInstance failed to create instance. (80004005
>   )"

**My Questions are**

1. Can we create a dll from scripts using python 3.2
2. How do we communicate b/w different versions of python which uses
   same modules like "pywin32"
3. What about virtual Environment and will it be useful in this case
   and if it is how do we use tat

Comment: Could you clarify: why a DLL has to be created? How are you trying to communicate with the DLL?

Comment: DLL is for registering shell extensions in windows explorer and it is a com server dll. My app exe communicates with this registered DLL using a pipe connection process. Basically I am trying change the overlay of the file icons like tortoise. But My app is built with python 3.2

Comment: Is it the exe that gives the error message in question?

Answer (score 0):

[Pyro4](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) can be used to communicate between processes running different Python interpreters (even over a network).